# Why are ticks not working for date format?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this simple python code that generates a simple X date y decimal plot.

My goal was to set the ticks to be the one unit less than the minimum **TO** the one unit plus the maximum, see code and plot below.

I don't see why it would not shows the X tick properly, the Y tick shows just fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#979899")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor("#d1d1d1")
ax.set_xlim(pd.to_datetime(["2018-11-18"]),pd.to_datetime(["2018-11-22"]))

plt.grid(True)
plt.title("This is a title",fontsize=16)

plt.yticks([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0])
plt.xticks(pd.to_datetime(["2018-11-18","2018-11-20","2018-11-22"]))

x1 = pd.to_datetime(["2018-11-19","2018-11-20","2018-11-21"])
y1 = [0.18,0.32,0.21]


for i,item in enumerate(y1):
    xP = x1[i]
    yP = y1[i]
    plt.text(xP,yP,str(item)+"%",fontsize=11)

plt.scatter(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The answer to the "why" of it is: `matplotlib` simply does not know that you intend the x-axis numbers to be treated as datestamps. By default Python, and hence `matplotlib`, assumes that your 8-digit literals are decimal numbers in the neighborhood of twenty million.  If your question is really "how do I plot with datestamps on the x axis?" then a google search for `matplotlib date tick labels` can get you to the following example code from the matplotlib project's own gallery: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/date.html

Comment: oh I totally see that you are saying

Comment: Why do you want to show ticks outside your data range?

Comment: If you just want a quick and dirty graph, you could use strings on the x-axis `x1 = ['20181120', '20181121', '20181122']`. But that will only work if the dates are increasing and all one day apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by converting to datetime object. Find solution below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#979899")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor("#d1d1d1")
plt.grid(True)
plt.title("This is a title",fontsize=16)

plt.xticks([datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,21),datetime.date(2018,11,22)],["11/20","11/21","11/22"])
plt.yticks([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0],["0.0","0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4","0.5","0.6","0.7","0.8","0.9","1.0"])

x1 = [datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,21),datetime.date(2018,11,22)]
y1 = [0.18,0.32,0.21]

for i,item in enumerate(y1):
    xP = x1[i]
    yP = y1[i]
    plt.text(xP,yP,str(item)+"%",fontsize=11)

plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide integers for the dates. So Matplotlib treats it like any number. And it tries to be smart about large numbers that are close together:

> The default formatter identifies when the x-data being plotted is a
>   small range on top of a large off set. To reduce the chances that the
>   ticklabels overlap the ticks are labeled as deltas from a fixed
>   offset. For example:
>
> `ax.plot(np.arange(2000, 2010), range(10))` will have tick of `0-9` with
>   an offset of `+2e3`. If this is not desired turn off the use of the
>   offset on the default formatter:
>
> `ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)` set the
>   rcParam `axes.formatter.useoffset=False` to turn it off globally, or set
>   a different formatter.
>   This is from the [docs of the `matplotlib.ticker` module](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html).